# How to print the first three digits after the decimal point of a floating number?

Tags: command-line, bash

I am new to BASH and learnt that both printf and echo write to the standard output. But, I came through the following example which reads an expression from input and computes the result to accuracy of 3 decimal places:

```
read exp
printf "%.3f\n" "$(echo $exp | bc -l)"
```

I don't get why echo is passed here as an argument in the the `printf` statement. Is there any other 
way to represent the statement using only `echo`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After `read exp`, you can use `echo` as follow:

```
$ echo "scale=3; $exp/1" | bc
9.456
```

But note that this command does not require `echo`:

```
$ bc <<< "scale=3; $exp/1"
9.456
```

**EDIT**: in order to get a rounded result you have to use the `printf` bash builtin as `bc` can't round values.

The following command works as expected:

```
 echo "scale=4; $exp" | bc | xargs printf "%.3f\n"
```

Comment: Your solution works right but the value is not precise to 3 decimal places .ex: 5+50*3/20 + (19*2)/7 your solution gives 17.928 but the answer is 17.929

Comment: @coder_r: To get rounded values, you have to have the bash `printf` builtin as `bc` alone won't round results

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using only `echo`:

- if you are using a decimal point (`.`) in your rational number:

  ```
  $ read exp
  123.4567
  $ int=${exp%%.*}
  $ rat=${exp##*.}
  $ echo $int.${rat:0:3}
  123.456
  ```
- if you are using a decimal comma (`,`) in your rational number (as I use and most part of continental Europe):

  ```
  $ read exp
  123,4567
  $ int=${exp%%,*}
  $ rat=${exp##*,}
  $ echo $int,${rat:0:3}
  123,456
  ```

For more info see [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide: Manipulating Strings](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html).